# Bottle.py MVC "Template not found."

Tags: linux, python-3.x, permissions, bottle

What am I trying to achieve:

Below is the code I am trying to run from \mongodb\blog\blog.py

```
@bottle.route('/')
def blog_index():

cookie = bottle.request.get_cookie("session")

username = sessions.get_username(cookie)

return bottle.template('blog_template',username=username))
```

After running blog.py from terminal and browsing to localhost:8082 I get the below error:

> Template 'blog_template' not found.

I had a similar problem last week which I fixed by changing the folder permissions to 777 (just to rule out permissions as the issue) but permissons are currently set to god on all sub folders to \mongodb and I still get the same issue.

The templates are all located in \mongodb\blog\views as specified in bottle.py documentation

currently permissions on that folder are as follows: (*regulator is the user I am logged in with*)

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 regulator regulator  718 Mar 23  2015 blog_template.tpl
-rwxrwxrwx 1 regulator regulator 1211 Mar 23  2015 entry_template.tpl
-rwxrwxrwx 1 regulator regulator  113 Mar 23  2015 error_template.tpl
-rwxrwxrwx 1 regulator regulator  816 Mar 23  2015 login.tpl
-rwxrwxrwx 1 regulator regulator  581 Mar 23  2015 newpost_template.tpl
-rwxrwxrwx 1 regulator regulator 1454 Mar 23  2015 signup.tpl
-rwxrwxrwx 1 regulator regulator  368 Mar 23  2015 welcome.tpl
```

I'm positive this is a permissions based issue and that I have overlooked something pretty basic but since I have been troubleshooting this for last 3 hours I would appreciate some fresh eyes to give it look over.

What permissions need to be in place for bottly.py to work? Is this documented anywhere (ive looked through http://bottlepy.org/docs/ can could not find this info)?

--------------------EDIT-------------------

Since writing this I have also tried the following

I have recreated a new test project to test only the template parts  folder structure is

test 
|_test.py
|_views
   |__test.tpl

- I have tried to run this as SUDO and none sudo.
- All folder permissions are 777

The code in test.py is as follows

> ```
> from bottle import route, run, template
>
> @route('/hello')
> def hello():
>     ##return "<h1>Hello World!</h1>"
>     output = template('test')
>     return output
> run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
> ```

Permissions

```
regulator@HP-EB8460p-UbGnome:/mongodb$ ls -l /mongodb/test/*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  191 Jan 25 19:10 /mongodb/test/test.py

/mongodb/test/views:
total 4
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 141 Jan 25 19:12 test.tpl
```

and finally the .tpl folder

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Why wont I work!!</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>THIS IS A TEST</h1>
IF YOU CAN SEE THIS THE TEST WORKS!!!
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you didn't change the TEMPLATE_PATH?

```
bottle.TEMPLATE_PATH += './mongodb/blog/views' #change this to the place your templates are found in
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks,Nope unfortunately that did not resolve the problem!

Comment: @WarrenGardner - Maybe update your post with a small working example?

Comment: Well the one what was working last week is not not working so i am unable to post a working example. I am going to install bottle.py on my *shudders* Windows machine as the folder permissions should not be an issue